# Im Facing a Problem With Destructor Called Twice in C++

Tags: c++, destructor, delete-operator

EDIT: I had to use `unique_ptr` or follow the rule-of-five I'm still learning about it so I used `unique_ptr` and it worked. But I have a question, the destructor now is being called twice and I think that is no problem as long as the block of memory that the pointer is pointing to is not being freed twice, Right??

I made a simple "String" class in c++ (Know it from The Cherno). So I made it and it seems to work well until I decided to add an empty constructor to be able to initialize it with no parameter but when I did that the destructor is being called twice.

```
// here is the header file
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class String
{
private:
    //Hold the raw of chars in the heap memory
    char* m_Buffer;
    //The size of the buffer in heap
    unsigned int m_Size;
public:
    //An empty Constructor
    String()
        : m_Buffer(nullptr), m_Size(0)
    {
        cout << "created Empty." << endl;
    }

    // A Constructor
    String(const char* string)
    {
        m_Size = strlen(string);
        m_Buffer = new char[m_Size + 1];
        memcpy(m_Buffer, string, m_Size + 1);
        m_Buffer[m_Size] = 0;
    }

    // A destructor
    ~String()
    {
        cout << "Destroy!!" << endl;
        

        delete[] m_Buffer;
    }

    // Function resposable for coping
    String(const String& other)
        : m_Size(other.m_Size)
    {
        m_Buffer = new char[m_Size + 1];
        memcpy(m_Buffer, other.m_Buffer, m_Size + 1);
    }
    

    char& operator[](unsigned int& index)
    {
        return m_Buffer[index];
    }


        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const String& other);
    };

    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const String& other)
    {
        stream << other.m_Buffer << endl;
        return stream;
    }

    


       //here is the main file

    #include "LclString.h"
    int main()
    
    {
        String a = "asdc";
    
        a = "ads"; // The Destructor is being called here the first time 
        
        cin.get();
    } // and here is the second time
```

A piece of advice will be appreciated
......................................

Comment: Define an assignment operator to follow [The Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three

Comment: Consider using `std::unique_ptr<char[]> m_Buffer` instead of `char* m_Buffer`. The compiler won't let you make this mistake, and you won't need to write a destructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your destructor calls `delete[] m_Buffer`. A pointer may never be deleted twice. If you do delete a pointer twice, then the behaviour of the program will be undefined. You must avoid ever doing that. To achieve avoiding that, you must make sure that no two instances of the class have the same pointer value in the member.

Consider what the implicitly generated assignment operator of your class does. It copies all members from the right hand operand to the left hand operand. Can you see why that is a problem? All members include the `m_Buffer` pointer. The assignment operator will cause two instances of the class to have the same pointer. And when the second instance is destroyed, it deletes that same pointer again. And the behaviour of the program is undefined.

There is another related problem, the implicit assignment operator overwrites the old `m_Buffer`. Who's going to delete the pointer that was overwritten? No-one is going to delete it because the value was lost by the assignment. That's a memory leak.

Conclusion:

- Avoid using owning bare pointers.
- Avoid using new and delete directly.
- If you have a user defined destructor, then you probalby also need user defined copy/move constructor and assignment operator. This is known as rule of 5 (previously rule of 3). If you use smart pointers instead of owning bare pointers, then you usually don't need a user defined destructor.

Comment: Thank you very much, you've clarified a lot for me.